# Kernel-Debugging a windows guest system from a linux system - Setup not working

Tags: linux, windows, debugging, vmware, windbg

I'm trying to kernel debug an application on my *Guest - WindowsXP OS*

My host is a *Ubuntu 14.04 x64* with VMware Workstation 12 installed.

*The Debugger Guest os* is *Windows 7* with WinDBG installed.

I've read this article from vmware:
https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_devices_serial_advanced_example_debugging.html

https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_devices_serial_2vms.html

And i configured my Machines as i understood from the article but it just wont work. One thing i didnt really understand and this might be my problem, is what the `NamedPipe` should be configured as?
Should i be using the `\\.\pipe\[NAME]` syntax or the `/tmp/[NAME]` one?

Obviously from within the `Windows 7 - Debugger` machine it will not recognize the `/tmp/[Name]` one. So which one is it?

Here are my configurations:

**WindowsXP (Debugged guest os)**:

1. Use socket (Named pipe)
2. \\.\pipe\DebugPort
3. From: *Server* To: *A Virtual Machine*
4. Yield CPU on poll

bootcfg

```
Boot Loader Settings
--------------------
timeout: 30
default: multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS

Boot Entries
------------
Boot entry ID:   1
Friendly Name:   "Microsoft Windows XP Professional"
Path:            multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS
OS Load Options: /noexecute=optin /fastdetect /debug /debugport=COM1: /baudrate=115200
```

**Windows7 (The debugger with WinDBG)**

1. Use socket (Named pipe)
2. \\.\pipe\DebugPort
3. From: *Client* To: *A Virtual Machine*
4. Yield CPU on poll

Now opening `WinDBG` on my *Windows7*, Hitting CTRL + K for KernelDebugging options, going to the `COM' Tab and configured as the following:

1. Baud Rate: 115200
2. Port: \\.\pipe\DebugPort
3. Pipe [Checked]
4. Reconnect [Checked]

Now resetting the `Guest XP` os results in nothing.. i dont get anything on my WinDBG client
What am i missing? Is my port naming convention wrong because im using a linux host?

Comment: I am not sure but would guess the pipe will be a file accessible to both vms residing on the host system. So in your case /tmp/...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a few issues here

1. Use linux format pipes/sockets - /tmp/, e.g. /tmp/dbg, if your host OS is linux
2. In windbg (Debugger system), just mention the name of port, i.e. COM1, not full pipe name (which is used, when debugging on the host OS itself, instead of across VMs)
3. In windbg (Debugger system), uncheck pipe
4. Also, "Yield CPU on poll" option is not required for debugger (Windows 7, here)

I'm able to connect windbg across Windows 7 VMs (one debugger & another debuggee) on Ubuntu 14.04 & Workstation 11.1.3

Answer (score 0):

you have installed two windows operating systems in two seperate virtual machines inside a single physical host which runs some flavour of linux 
if such is the case and you prefer to use named pipe

```
1) edit the boot.ini in xp (no bcdsettings available in xp guest) 
2) add a serial port on both the virtual machines 
3) use named pipe \\.\pipe\com_1  on both virtual machines
4) assign one end as server and other end as virtual machine in first vm
5) assign one end as client and other end as virtual machine in second vm
6) restart
```

this link has some fancy crap but you can refer the images
http://www.woodmann.com/forum/entry.php?234-connect-two-virtual-machines-on-one-physical-host-and-use-wdeb386-to-debug-win98-app

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but this is not working
Might there be problem because im using `Win-xp SP2` and not SP3?

Comment: **it is not working means == vague  Description or No Description of a problem** no conceptually os shouldn't matter  if you checked the linked articles images you may notice the vms running there are windows98   on a physical host  theoratically the physical host should be able to run the virtual machine  and the virtual machine must be able to run any os  and if they are connectible in a physical world they should be connectible in the virtual world too